# Laravel Display foreign key table value

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Basically I have 2 tables, which is **maintenance** and **user** here. I would like to display user name from maintenance table. The following error occurred in my code:

> Attempt to read property "name" on int

I tends to find existing solution on StackOverflow. However, most of them are returning
model in the controller, such as $**maintennace = Maintenance::with(['user'])**; into the view. However, I was returning DB so I am not sure how to solve this problem.

**MaintenanceController**

```
public function ViewMaintenance() {
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $maintenance = DB::table('maintenances')->where('landlord_id', $id)->paginate(5);

    return view('maintenance.maintenance-status', compact('maintenance'));
}
```

**Maintenance Model**

```
class Maintenance extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'document',
        'category',
        'status',
        'landlord_id',
        'tenant_id',
        'property_id',
    ];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'role',
        'email',
        'avatar',
        'password',
        'phone_number'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function maintenance() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Maintenance');
    }
}
```

The info that I would want to display is name from user database. For your information landlord_id is foreign key based on user table id.

> **{{ $maintain-> landlord_id ->name}}**

**Maintenance.blade.php**

```
<tbody>
    @if (!empty($maintenance) && $maintenance ->count())
        @foreach ($maintenance as $key=>$maintain)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
            <td>{{ $maintain-> title}}</td>
            <td>{{ $maintain-> title }}</td>
            <td>{{ $maintain-> category }}</td>
            @if ($maintain-> status =='Unresolved')
                <td><span class="badge bg-danger">{{ $maintain-> status}}</span></td>
            @endif
            @if ($maintain-> status =='Resolved')
                <td><span class="badge bg-success">{{ $maintain-> status}}</span></td>
            @endif
            <td>**{{ $maintain-> landlord_id ->name}}**</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    @else 
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6"> There are no data</td>
        </tr>
    @endif
</tbody>
```

Database Images:

[image: Table User]

[image: Table Maintenance]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your relation to

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'landlord_id', 'id');
}
```

Because you are using `landlord_id` rather than `user_id`

Comment: Hi thanks for your tips! I had changed my this line of code into `return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'landlord_id');`

Comment: Your welcome!
 So you can mark as correct answer (you marked incorrect answer as correct), to others not get confused. because they don't read comments <3

Answer (score 0):

In you **MaintenanceController**

```
$id = Auth::user()->id;
$maintenance = DB::table('maintenances AS m')->leftJoin('users AS u', 'm.landlord_id', '=', 'u.id')->where('u.id', '=', $id)->get()->paginate(5)
```

After that, you just display user name.

```
{{ $maintenance->name }}
```

You can do test before executing code in MaintenanceController.

```
dd($maintenance);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. I had successfully solved my problem through another way but didn't manage to try out this method